# looping audio file using timed script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting, cron

I want to play an audio file then after the audio file is finished playing wait 30mins and have it play the audio file again.  I would like to do this several times.

I know I could just make one large audio file but the file would be very large and I need to email to other people it's easier to make the audio file and use some type of script to do this.

```
Example Loop: 
play audio file to the end then wait 30mins,
play audio file to the end then wait 30mins,
play audio file to the end then wait 30mins,
etc..
```

**PS: The audio file could be any length.**

I know about crontab

```
crontab -e
*/30 * * * * /path/to/your/command
```

But this doesn't wait for the audio file to finish playing or give me the ability to say how many times it should run.

I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, or I'm missing something.  What you need is something like:

```
NTIMES=5

count=0
while [ $count -lt $NTIMES ]
do
  mplayer the_sound_file
  sleep 1800                         # 1800 seconds == 30 min
  count=`expr $count + 1`
done
```

I have used older syntax so that this will run on any bourne-like shell (not just bash).